# AppEngine Datastore get entities that have ALL items in list property

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, listproperty

I want to implement some kind of tagging functionality to my app. I want to do something like...

```
class Item(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  tags = db.ListProperty(str)
```

Suppose I get a search that have 2 or more tags. Eg. "restaurant" and "mexican".

Now, I want to get Items that have ALL, in this case 2, given tags.

How do I do that? Or is there a better way to implement what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want tags to be stored as 'db.ListProperty(db.Category)' and then query them with something like:

```
   return db.Query(Item)\
             .filter('tags = ', expected_tag1)\
             .filter('tags = ', expected_tag2)\
             .order('name')\
             .fetch(256)
```

(Unfortunately I can't find any good documentation for the db.Category type. So I cannot definitively say this is the right way to go.) Also note, that in order to create a db.Category you need to use:

```
new_item.tags.append(db.Category(unicode(new_tag_text)))
```

Comment: So I'll just add a ".filter()" for every additional tag I get. Hmmmmm... Any idea how Datastore performance will be with something like this?

Comment: Yes, I just verified on my own blog (written using db.Category, AppEngine, etc.) That will work.  I suspect it won't be too bad -- I think that is the difference between db.Category and just a list of strings -- but I could be wrong.

Comment: Be wary of "exploding indexes" here.  If the tags property has 40 values in it, and you look for 4 tags, you're looking at 40^4 index entries for a every single entity.  There's no way to get around this in a query without doing your own processing.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I'd love to learn more about what db.Category is actually doing, especially if it impacts my app's indexes.

Comment: It was posted to the google group that the difference between a db.Category and other types was that a category object should have 'semantic' meaning I suppose more than just a word I guess some words can't be categories.

Comment: @Riley has things backwards. Exploding indexes are an indexing issue, not a querying one: If you define a custom index that indexes a list property four times, you will get n!/(n-4)! index entries for each entity. Unfortunately, the query @Chris describes _will_ require this exploding index, because it has a sort order. If you drop the sort order, the query can be executed by built-in indexes using the merge-join strategy. You could then apply the ordering in-memory.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Fair enough that n^4 is a little bigger than n!/(n-4)!, but do I really have it _backwards_?  I meant that the index for this query would explode, not that the query would explode.  I see now that the merge-join strategy can perform the query quickly on the built-in indices, but besides that oversight am I misunderstanding the nature of exploding indexes?

Comment: @Riley You said "you're looking at 40^4 index entries for [a] every single entity". Perhaps your wording was unclear, but that reads to me as if that's the number of rows the query has to scan to find one result, rather than the number of index entries that have to be inserted.

Comment: @Nick Johnson Thanks for the clarification - I was (trying to be!) referring to index entries.  There's a lot to keep in mind at this level of complexity!

Answer (score 0):

use db.ListProperty(db.Key) instead,which stores a list of entity's keys.

models:

```
 class Profile(db.Model):
 data_list=db.ListProperty(db.Key)

 class Data(db.Model):
 name=db.StringProperty()
```

views:

```
   prof=Profile()
   data=Data.gql("")#The Data entities you want to fetch

   for data in data:
       prof.data_list.append(data)
```

/// Here data_list stores the keys of Data entity

**Data.get(prof.data_list)** will get all the Data entities whose key are in the data_list attribute

Comment: Please don't abuse the moderator flag.